# Python: extract a 2D array from a 3D array

Tags: python, arrays, opencv, numpy

I have a 3D numpy array (1L, 420L, 580L) the 2nd and 3rd dimension is a gray scale image that I want to display using openCV. How do I pull the 2D array from the 3D array?

I created a short routine to do this, but I bet there is a better way.

```
# helper function to remove 1st dimension
def pull_image(in_array):

    rows = in_array.shape[1]    # vertical
    cols = in_array.shape[2]    # horizontal

    out_array = np.zeros((rows, cols), np.uint8)    # create new array to hold image data

    for r in xrange(rows):
        for c in xrange(cols):            
            out_array[r, c] = in_array[:, r, c]
    return out_array
```

Comment: Use `np.squeeze`. Or just extract the first element to lose the extra singleton dim.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you always only have the first dimension == 1, then you could simply reshape the array...

```
if in_array.shape[0] == 1:
    return in_array.reshape(in_array.shape[1:])
```

otherwise, you can use numpy's advanced list slicing...

```
else:
    return in_array[0,:,:]
```